# Can anybody tell me how to enter two input values in C#?

Tags: c#

I am having trouble inputting two different input values into C# for one of my assignments. It doesn't seem to want to debug with the way that i have it set up.

- The output value is: Miles Per Gallon
- Input values are: Miles
  Traveled, Gallons of Gas Used

This is how I have it set up so far and it still won't work for me.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    float milespergallon, milestraveled, gallonsofgasused;
    string textLine;

    Console.Write("What is the total miles traveled and gallons of gas used? ");
    textLine = Console.ReadLine();  // read in text from console

    milestraveled and gallonsofgasused = float.Parse(textLine); // convert text into floating point
    milespergallon =  miles / gallons;    // calculate mpg = miles / gallons

    Console.Write("Miles Per Gallon: ");
    Console.WriteLine(milespergallon.ToString());// Output miles per gallon to console

    Console.ReadLine();                  // Wait for return key press
}
```

Comment: your would have to provide at least with the code you have so far. And please clarify what you mean with "into c sharp"?! I just guess you mean a console application?

Comment: You need to provide more details -- is this a web application or Windows Forms? Also, you need to include the relevant code. If you want people to help you, you need to put in the effort to explain your question and give posters the information they need.

Comment: If that `float` declaration is your actual code then I'm sure the compiler is trying to tell you that your variable declaration is very, very broken.  Variable names can't have spaces in them.

Comment: i'm using microsoft visual C# 2010 Express.

Comment: how can i post a screen shot of the code that i have already written?

Comment: Simply use 2 WriteLine+ReadLine combinations to get 2 variables. One at a time.

Comment: an error comes up saying that gallonsofgasused is "expected" and apparently somehow wrong

Comment: could you show an example of where to put the WriteLine+ReadLine combos? I'm very inexperienced with this and it's my first time doing it on my own

Answer (score 1):

```
double milespergallon, milestraveled, gallonsofgasused;    // don't fiddle with float
string textLine;

Console.Write("What is the total miles traveled? ");
textLine = Console.ReadLine();  // read in text from console
milesTraveled = double.Parse(textLine);

Console.Write("What is the total gallons of gas used? ");
textLine = Console.ReadLine();  // read in text from console
gallonsOfGasUsed= double.Parse(textLine);

...
```

Comment: @user2829274 Accept the answer if it suits your needs. There is a tick mark on the left.